# How to validate authenticode for Javascript in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, powershell, code-signing, authenticode

I was able to sign a js file with PowerShell Set-AuthenticodeSignature.
After that i can see signature appeared in file in form of:

```
// SIG // Begin signature block
// SIG // MIIKgAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIKcTCCCm0CAQExCzAJBgUr
// SIG // ....
// SIG // End signature block
```

I can validate signature using Get-AuthenticodeSignature. It says that sig is valid, but I cant find a way to validate signature in C# code.
All of those options failed:

1. X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile
2. [X509Certificate object c# performance and memory issues alternative – fixed](http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2016/02/17/x509certificate-object-c-performance-memory-issues-alternative-fixed/)
3. Used WinVerifyTrust from Wintrust.dll
4. Ported part of Get-AuthenticodeSignature from PowerShell!

Maybe there are some specific apis to validate js signatures?

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered similar problem and let me show what I did to solve this problem. Before I go , there are few assumptions I make now. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. wintrust is working for all other cases other than script files like
   .js or .vbs
2. You might have attempted "wintrustverify" from an
       console application (C#)

I figured it out this happens only with script files as I have mentioned above because wintrust behaves wierdly when its methods are being executed from free-threaded apartment model (MTA). Once it's been wrapped inside a STA thread, it started working for me. Later I came to know it is a historical issue that we should have taken a precaution when we deal with any COM components interoperations from .Net application.

Here is the code snippet, you can replace the verifysignature with your wintrust code logic and try. I hope this helps.

```
            public static void CheckSignature()
            {
                STAApartment apt = new STAApartment();
                var result = apt.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    return VerifySignature(@".\signedjsfile.js", false);
                });
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }

            private static WinVerifyTrustResult VerifySignature(string filePath, bool verifySignatureOnly)
            {

                using (var wtd = new WinTrustData(new WinTrustFileInfo(filePath))
                {
                    dwUIChoice = WintrustUIChoice.WTD_UI_NONE,
                    dwUIContext = WinTrustDataUIContext.WTD_DATA_UI_EXECUTE,
                    fdwRevocationChecks = WinTrustDataRevocationChecks.WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_WHOLECHAIN,
                    dwStateAction = WintrustAction.WTD_STATEACTION_IGNORE,
                    dwProvFlags = verifySignatureOnly ? WintrustProviderFlags.WTD_HASH_ONLY_FLAG : WintrustProviderFlags.WTD_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN
                })
                {
                    var result = WinTrust.WinVerifyTrust(
                        WinTrust.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, new Guid(WinTrust.WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2), wtd
                    );
                    return result;
                }
            }

            public class STAApartment
            {
                public T Invoke<T>(Func<T> func)
                {
                    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            tcs.SetResult(func());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            tcs.SetException(e);
                        }
                    });
                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    thread.Start();                
                    return tcs.Task.Result;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

WinVerifyTrust supports verifying files other than executables using the [WTD_CHOICE_BLOB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388205(v=vs.85).aspx) flag. Make sure you provide the [WINTRUST_BLOB_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388202(v=vs.85).aspx) struct with the correct [subject interface package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721625(v=vs.85).aspx#_security_subject_interface_package_gly) (SIP). From what I can see, Get-AuthenticodeSignature command uses the PowerShell SIP [{603bcc1f-4b59-4e08-b724-d2c6297ef351}](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/security/nativeMethods.cs#L836) to verify the signature. I assume Set-AuthenticodeSignature uses the same SIP to sign the script.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have checked, that WTD_CHOICE_BLOB is used, but it returns 0x800b0100(No signature) after validation. But signature is there in file. Here blob is being initialized https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/security/Authenticode.cs#L529. File is loaded into memory with File.ReadAllText.

Comment: A closer look at   Did you also try to provide a file path only (so WINTRUST_FILE_INFO is used instead)

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too quickly... A closer look at [Get-AuthenticodeSignature](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/security/SignatureCommands.cs#L281) shows that fileContent == null, so WINTRUST_FILE_INFO is used instead. Did you try that?

Comment: Tried both. With file path only WTGetSignatureInfo error code is SIGNATURE_STATE.SIGNATURE_STATE_UNSIGNED_MISSING.  Sample file: https://gist.github.com/aanufriyev/cd8b69b0f24927fe52ce0111ec4075dc

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that JS file are signed with a different SIP. You can use [CryptSIPRetrieveSubjectGuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc542590(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out the SIP GUID for a file. Then feed that GUID to WinVerifyTrust.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. But it is weird, because validation works in PowerShell and a subset of command functionality ported - not :(

Comment: Got this SIP for js files(11d438ce-a3a2-1000-4bd3-509000000000) and TRUST_E_PROVIDER_UNKNOWN = 0x800b0001 error.