# Reading digital certificate from the file

Tags: c#, cryptography, x509certificate2

I signed a file using Signtool.exe and now I am trying to load the certificate attached to the file using the following method

```
var cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromSignedFile(filePath);
```

but his line throws an error "Cannot find the requested object.". When I try reading the certificate from a microsoft signed dll e.g. **EntityFramework.dll**, it works without any problems. I thought it could be because I don't have the certificate in the Trusted Store but even after adding it there, it continues to throw error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Error sound like either the filePath is bad or the application doesn't have the privilege to read the path and/or the file.

Comment: And make sure that file is signed. Open file properties and check `Digital Signatures` tab.

Comment: Is says in the API doc that it only supports ASN.1 DER. What's the value of the first byte of the file? Is it `30` (hex)? What does `file <filePath>` return?

Comment: @Crypt32 the file is signed. I can see the digital signatures tab.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes <filepath> is the location of the file

Comment: Right. But the certificate tools detect the encoding of the file automatically. That's why I'm asking. Try opening the file in a text editor otherwise.

Comment: Ok it was failing because I signed a javascript file. It seems it cannot read the signature from the javascript file(not sure why) because when I signed using a dll it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wintrust component to collect the signature information

```
   [DllImportAttribute("wintrust.dll", EntryPoint = "WTGetSignatureInfo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern int WTGetSignatureInfo([InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszFile, [InAttribute()] System.IntPtr hFile, SIGNATURE_INFO_FLAGS sigInfoFlags, ref SIGNATURE_INFO psiginfo, ref System.IntPtr ppCertContext, ref System.IntPtr phWVTStateData);
```

This will collect the signature details from any signable files that microsoft prescribes. But make sure that you execute the given function under single threaded apartment model. Otherwise you will find weird results for signed script files like .js/.vbs and etc.

Please refer [How to validate authenticode for Javascript in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138445/how-to-validate-authenticode-for-javascript-in-c-sharp) for more details.